# jcodec video from images and sound

Tags: android, image, video, jcodec

I am creating a video from a image and a mp4 sound on my sd  card on android  from jcodec.I am getting output video but there is no voice and video is play on vlc but on android player continuous looping please help me

Following is my code segment

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.jcodec.codecs.h264.H264Encoder;
import org.jcodec.codecs.h264.H264Utils;
import org.jcodec.common.NIOUtils;
import org.jcodec.common.SeekableByteChannel;
import org.jcodec.common.model.ColorSpace;
import org.jcodec.common.model.Picture;
import org.jcodec.containers.mp4.Brand;
import org.jcodec.containers.mp4.MP4Packet;
import org.jcodec.containers.mp4.TrackType;
import org.jcodec.containers.mp4.muxer.FramesMP4MuxerTrack;
import org.jcodec.containers.mp4.muxer.MP4Muxer;
import org.jcodec.scale.RgbToYuv420;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;

public class SequenceEncoder {
    private SeekableByteChannel ch;
    private Picture toEncode;
    private RgbToYuv420 transform;
    private H264Encoder encoder;
    private ArrayList<ByteBuffer> spsList;
    private ArrayList<ByteBuffer> ppsList;
    private FramesMP4MuxerTrack outTrack;
    private ByteBuffer _out;
    private int frameNo;
    private MP4Muxer muxer;

    public SequenceEncoder(File out) throws IOException {
        this.ch = NIOUtils.writableFileChannel(out);

        // Transform to convert between RGB and YUV
        transform = new RgbToYuv420(0, 0);

        // Muxer that will store the encoded frames
        muxer = new MP4Muxer(ch, Brand.MP4);

        // Add video track to muxer
        outTrack = muxer.addTrackForCompressed(TrackType.VIDEO, 25);

        // Allocate a buffer big enough to hold output frames
        _out = ByteBuffer.allocate(1920 * 1080 * 6);

        // Create an instance of encoder
        encoder = new H264Encoder();

        // Encoder extra data ( SPS, PPS ) to be stored in a special place of
        // MP4
        spsList = new ArrayList<ByteBuffer>();
        ppsList = new ArrayList<ByteBuffer>();

    }

    public void encodeImage(Bitmap bi) throws IOException {
        // encodeNativeFrame(AWTUtil.fromBufferedImage(bi));
        encodeNativeFrame(fromBitmap(bi));
    }

    public void encodeNativeFrame(Picture pic) throws IOException {
        if (toEncode == null) {
            toEncode = Picture.create(pic.getWidth(), pic.getHeight(),
                    ColorSpace.YUV420);
        }

        // Perform conversion
        transform.transform(pic, toEncode);

        // Encode image into H.264 frame, the result is stored in '_out' buffer
        _out.clear();
        ByteBuffer result = encoder.encodeFrame(_out, toEncode);

        // Based on the frame above form correct MP4 packet
        spsList.clear();
        ppsList.clear();
        H264Utils.encodeMOVPacket(result, spsList, ppsList);

        // Add packet to video track
        outTrack.addFrame(new MP4Packet(result, frameNo, 25, 1, frameNo, true,
                null, frameNo, 0));
        frameNo++;
    }

    public void finish() throws IOException {
        // Push saved SPS/PPS to a special storage in MP4
        outTrack.addSampleEntry(H264Utils
                .createMOVSampleEntry(spsList, ppsList));

        // Write MP4 header and finalize recording
        muxer.writeHeader();
        NIOUtils.closeQuietly(ch);
    }

    public static Picture fromBitmap(Bitmap src) {
        Picture dst = Picture.create((int) src.getWidth(),
                (int) src.getHeight(), ColorSpace.RGB);
        fromBitmap(src, dst);
        return dst;
    }

    public static void fromBitmap(Bitmap src, Picture dst) {
        int[] dstData = dst.getPlaneData(0);
        int[] packed = new int[src.getWidth() * src.getHeight()];

        src.getPixels(packed, 0, src.getWidth(), 0, 0, src.getWidth(),
                src.getHeight());

        for (int i = 0, srcOff = 0, dstOff = 0; i < src.getHeight(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < src.getWidth(); j++, srcOff++, dstOff += 3) {
                int rgb = packed[srcOff];
                dstData[dstOff] = (rgb >> 16) & 0xff;
                dstData[dstOff + 1] = (rgb >> 8) & 0xff;
                dstData[dstOff + 2] = rgb & 0xff;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: did u find any solution?

Comment: Getting null exception on this line.  dstData[dstOff] = (rgb >> 16) & 0xff;