# Create video from series of images using android

Tags: java, android, ffmpeg, x264, jcodec

I'm trying to write an android application in which we allow user to create video from series of images.
I did lot of investigation like C/C++ libraries FFMPEG, X264. These can be used using NDK, but i dont know how to use it via NDK, i also did investigation but did not get about this. 
I find another library JCodec It is java based. I tried different codes of JCodec but did not get any success. Below are Links related to JCodec:

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10284708/android-make-animated-video-from-list-of-images), 
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11006910/encode-a-video-into-h264-using-bufferedimages) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17695475/jcodec-vedio-from-images-and-sound).

Now can anyone guide me about this question and can i have some suggestion how to implement this feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FFMpeg or X264 is your best bet to create videos from a series of images. Both of them have detailed instructions on how to integrate this library into an android application. You can just add the *.so files into your jni/libs folder and invoke them from your Java code. I recommend you read thru the instructions provided on the FFMPeg site. You can also find the precompiled FFMPeg library [here](https://github.com/android-native-libraries)